# Using ORDER BY with ROLLUP

Tags: mysql

been struggling with this all day now trying various combos without any joy if anyone can help? I use WITH ROLLUP to sum  a Total column which adds a row to foot of table outputting each columns sum.

I now need to order the last column [profits] descending so highest number is at top. I have achieved this using query below but it also sorts the ROLLUP row, is there a method to have the rollup as a separate entity so the ORDER BY is only done on normal records?

```
Select
  *
From
  (Select
      c.ContactFullName As Adviser,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Jan,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 2, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Feb,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 3, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Mar,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 4, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Apr,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 5, b.LeadCost, 0)) As May,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 6, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Jun,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 7, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Jul,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 8, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Aug,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 9, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Sep,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 10, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Oct,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 11, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Nov,
      Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 12, b.LeadCost, 0)) As Decb,
      Sum(b.LeadCost) As LeadCosts,
      Sum(b.CaseCommission) As GrossComm,
      (Sum(b.CaseCommission) * 40 / 100) As GHL_Comm,
      (Sum(b.CaseCommission) * 40 / 100 - Sum(b.LeadCost)) As Profit
    From
      tblcontacts a Inner Join
      tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactID Inner Join
      mi_tblcontacts c On c.Mi_ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo Inner Join
      tblreferral d On d.RefferalID = a.ContactReferrelSource
    Group By
      c.ContactFullName With Rollup) q
Order By
  q.Profit Desc
```

Any help appreciated.

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT *, If(ContactFullName is null, 1, 0) as rolledup 
FROM ( .... giant inner select goes here ...)
ORDER BY rolledup asc, q.profit desc
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, when I try this it tells me 'Unknown Column ContactFullName in Field list'?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I just changed ContactFullName to q.adviser and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you order by profit desc then you will get the rollup column as first row and that is not meaningfull.So I guess you cant do like that. As far as I know you cant simply change the order of one coulmn and keeping the rest of columns order as fixed.